# Do flight recorders need more efficient antennas?

Tags: flight-recorders

At a frequency of 37.5 kHz, a quarter wavelength is about 2 km (1.24 miles) long. How does the black box efficiently radiate anything if it is not attached to 2 km of antenna?

Answer (score 18):

The short version of the answer is `37.5KHz is not "radio frequency", it's "audio frequency"`, so an antenna is not necessary - just a (very loud) speaker, which is basically what the pinger is.

---

Specifically, the 37.5KHz "pinger" tones used in the Underwater Locator Beacons that are bolted onto Cockpit Voice Recorder / Flight Data Recorder "black boxes" are in the low end of what we call [ultrasonic frequencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrasound). Water is [generally a good conductor of sound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwater_acoustics) ([with at least one notable exception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocline)), so it is usually possible for sonar detection equipment to "hear" the pinger tones at reasonable distances (with the interpretation of "reasonable" varying based on the depth of the area being searched - much like in air the sound intensity falls off as distance from the source increases, so if we're listening at the surface of the ocean a pinger in 500 feet of water will have a larger coverage footprint than the same pinger in 5000 feet of water).

Comment: Your question begs the equally-interesting radio-frequency question: "Aviation band radios operate in the frequency range 108MHz-137MHz (about 7ft to 9ft wavelength), so how can our aircraft radios efficiently radiate without being connected to 9 feet of antenna?" -

Comment: While the wavelength is 7-9 ft, the optimal antenna is (depending on antenna design) usually half, and sometimes a quarter (as mentioned in the question), so 2-4ft antenna would do the trick, which is, if I'm not mistaken, roughly the size used.

Comment: A quarter-wave antenna is easy to make: you've got the aluminum skin of the airplane to act as your reflecting plane, so it's just a matter of bracing two feet of wire so it's sticking straight out.

Comment: @falstro the point of that comment was to inspire someone to [ask the question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) so we could give a proper answer with the quarter-wave dipole diagram and the RF theory (which will not fit in a comment) :-)